# After reload label in code , uiview go back to first position in story board

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield

I have a problem with a uiview that placed in story board in one position and after the app start I move the uiview to second position with animate With Duration with a button from code.

```
 int alpha = -212;
if(!flag)
{
    alpha = 212;
}
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.8 animations:^(void)
 {

     keyboardView.frame = CGRectMake(keyboardView.frame.origin.x, keyboardView.frame.origin.y + alpha, keyboardView.frame.size.width, keyboardView.frame.size.height);

 }
                 completion:nil];
```

After I do something like reload label or change something in text filed the 
uiview back to story board position.

```
  labelTest1.text = tempTextFiled;


        [textField setText:tempTextFiled];
```

How can I keep the uiview stay in the second position  ?

Comment: Are you using `Autolayout` in your storyboard? If you are, you'll need to animate the constraints on the view, not its frame. The frame is calculated based on the constraints the view is given.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to create this view without the storyboard (code only). this will fix your issue.